# Searching between 2 elements in C++ using std::find

Tags: c++

I'm trying to search for an element in a vector between 2 iterators (excluding the iterators). That's what I tried:

```
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int>::const_iterator low_it = nums.begin();
    vector<int>::const_iterator high_it = nums.end()-1;
    vector<vector<int>> ret;

    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    while (low_it < high_it) {
        vector<int>::const_iterator find_it = find(low_it+1, high_it, -(*low_it + *high_it));
        if ((find_it != nums.end())) {
            ret.emplace_back(vector<int>{*low_it, *high_it, *find_it});
            low_it += 1;
            high_it += -1;
        } else if ((*low_it + *high_it) > 0)
            high_it += -1;
        else
            low_it += 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Edit: added the full function im trying to write. My goal is to find all 3 numbers in an array which add up to 0.
The code compiles without any warnings, thats how I've been compiling:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -g -Wall -pedantic 3sum.cpp
```

Comment: does it compile? Does it produce expected output? Thats what you should tell us first.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in `while` loop while neither low_it or high_it don't change? Provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) so that we could help.

Comment: find searches between two iterators already, you don't need to use a loop as well.

Comment: Both `nums.end()-1` and `low_it+1` are undefined if the vector is empty. `std::find`  already excludes the upper boundary (all standard library ranges are half-open, for good reasons). If you know that the vector is sorted, use `lower_bound` instead of `find`.

Comment: What this suppose to do? What does it mean `threeSum`? Which version of C++ standard you can use (by code style it looks like C++98)? Since you are working on sorted data did you consider `std::lower_bound`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` almost in all cases will run infinitely, since neither `low_it` nor `high_it` changes and if the condition once succeeds, it will succeed forever.

So just write:

```
vector<int>::const_iterator find_it = find(low_it+1, high_it, -(*low_it + *high_it));
```

Some other subtle defect will cause an issue if `nums` vector is empty. You can't get `nums.end()-1` for empty array since it will refer to the object "prior" to the vector, which is undefined behavior.

You are trying to reinvent [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) which does exactly what you need.

```
auto threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    return std::equal_range(nums.begin(), nums.end(),-(*low_it + *high_it));
}
```

It will return the range of the numbers in the sorted range you are looking for.

The remaining questions are:

1. Do you have a real reason to reinvent the algorithm (like homework)?
2. Why to you need vector of vectors as return value? What the profit from it do you expect while all the elements are sorted and the range what is you are looking for?

Comment: I see.
I've added the full function im trying to write, so you can see my intention.
How would you go about to find the element in this case?

Comment: You are trying to reinvent `std::equal_range`(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) which does exactly what you need. Just use it or explain what is your reason to invent your version. It the latter case just see the sources of `std::equal_range`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see bug here:

```cpp
if ((find_it != nums.end())) {
```

This condition is always true since `std::find` will never return `nums.end()`! It nothing is found second argument of `std::find` is returned!

It becomes obvious when basic test is failing:
https://godbolt.org/z/Kejcn7K6E

Do you need fix or this hint is enough?

Also to speed thing up you can use `std::lower_bound` since you are working on sorted data.
Note also that it is possible to come up with better algorithm.